# Posicionar 2 divs en Paralelo usando CSS

Tags: html, css, posicionamiento

El problema esta en que quiero dejar el div con id "div_imagen" exactamente al lado del div con id "descripcion", al momento de introducir un párrafo en un div interno del div "descripcion" se me descuadra y se va para abajo, dejo el código para que podáis verlo.

Aquí abajo dejo todo el código que he escrito tanto el código html como el código css.

Gracias de antemano a cualquiera que ayude.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: static;
}

#div_imagen {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  width: 35%;
  height: 350px;
  background: red;
}

#descripcion {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 350px;
  background: orange;
  margin: -2px;
}

#div_titulo {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#div_parrafo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 275px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#parrafo1 {
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>prueba posicionamiento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div_imagen"></div>
    <div id="descripcion">
      <div id="div_titulo"></div>
      <div id="div_parrafo">
        <p id="parrafo1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus velit eu est hendrerit, non scelerisque metus consectetur. Vestibulum mi lectus, sollicitudin in ex euismod</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por qué posicionas al body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes problemas con overflows y margenes faltantes.
Te recomiendo siempre hacer el CSS usando la consola del navegador.
De este modo, podrás como es que funcionan los cambios y como se aplican en tiempo real.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#div_imagen {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  width: 35%;
  height: 350px;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#descripcion {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 350px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#div_titulo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 0vh;
  left: 0vw;
  text-align: center;
}

#div_parrafo {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 275px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parrafo1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>prueba posicionamiento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div_imagen">aca hay una imagen</div>
    <div id="descripcion">
      <div id="div_titulo">Super Titulo</div>
      <div id="div_parrafo">
        <p id="parrafo1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus velit eu est hendrerit, non scelerisque metus consectetur. Vestibulum mi lectus, sollicitudin in ex euismodasdasdasdasdasdasdasd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Al final buscando por internet encontré una forma de hacerlo con float left, igualmente muchas gracias me guardo tu forma de hacerlo y la de Daniel para tener mas posibilidades para usar

Answer (score 0):

Lo queyo haria en tu caso seria usar Flexbox [te dejo este enlace para aprender un poco mas sobre flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: static;
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#div_imagen {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  background: red;
}

#descripcion {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 350px;
  background: orange;
  margin: -2px;
}

#div_titulo {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#div_parrafo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 275px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#parrafo1 {
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>prueba posicionamiento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div id="div_imagen"></div>
        <div id="descripcion">
            <div id="div_titulo"></div>
            <div id="div_parrafo">
                <p id="parrafo1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus velit eu est hendrerit, non scelerisque metus consectetur. Vestibulum mi lectus, sollicitudin in ex euismod</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si vas a usar flexbox, entonces ya los position que usa el OP técnicamente no serían necesarios

Comment: conseguí hacerlo mediante float left dentro de un div padre, he escuchado que flexbox va muy bien, le echare un ojo muchas gracias